# Appointment created twice or thrice using EWS

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I've written an aspx webpage that created Appointments using EWS.
Everthing works fine except the appointements are created twice or thrice in the user's calendar.

Connection to EWS works fine, the appointment is created at page's first load if isPostback is false.
I tried debugging the code step by step and I'm sure the appointment creation function isn't called twice.

Has anybody else faced this issue ?

Thanks a lot

Edit : some piece of code to illustrate. But it's very simple and cannot explain where my issue comes from.
On the other hand, I forgot to mention that the call is made from a dynamic link generated in Excel. Users click on the link which calls the webpage. the page itself reads the parameters in the querystring and uses them to set some of the appointment properties (subject, body, StartDate, etc.). I didn't show this in the code since it does'nt seem relevant to me to explain the issue.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);
    service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("user", "pwd");
    service.AutodiscoverUrl("email@domain.com");
    
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        try
        {                       
            Appointment appointment = new Appointment(service);
            appointment.Subject = "subject";
            appointment.Body = "body";
            appointment.Body.BodyType = BodyType.HTML;
            appointment.Location = "adr";
            appointment.Start = StartDate;
            appointment.End = EndDate;
            appointment.InReplyTo = "myemail@domain.com";
            appointment.Save(SendInvitationsMode.SendToNone);
         }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. If the EWS API was so broken that it creates 2 or 3 appointments for every call, more people would have noticed.

Comment: What's your code and what *exactly* have you tried to fix it? I recommend you read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [edit] your question to add your code in the form of a [mcve]

Comment: Thanks for your (not very) kind answers :). I hadn't shown any code since it is pretty simple and cannot explain the issue. But I should have explained that the page is called from an Excel link since it could be an explaination.

Comment: I don't see any check if the appointment already exists. What if the user clicks the link / button multiple times? Wouldn't this create the same appointment multiple times?

Comment: @bassfader : indeed, there's no check that the appointment already exists. But I've checked it myself and I'm sure I clicked only one time and it generated the same appointment thrice. I've tested this many many times looking for the origin of the issue.

Comment: I would suggest as a test you modify you code generate a unique guid and add that to the subject each time the function is run, if you see the duplicates appointments with the same guid you know for sure its not your code being called multiple times. If you see different guids then you know where to look

Comment: @GlenScales : thanks for your answer. Indeed I get three different GUIDs when applying your idea. This led me to look for an issue in Excel and find this : https://superuser.com/questions/1359127/excel-click-on-hyperlink-calls-url-three-times . The problem does'nt come from EWS, neither from my code but from an Excel feature. I don't really know how to set a workaround up yet.

Answer (score 0):

Since the issue doesn't come from EWS but from Excel. Since it seems to be an Excel feature that can't be deactivated, I chose to implement a solution that checks if an appointment with the same object already exists in the calendar and to create it only if I can't find a duplicate object at the same date and time.